# How to define type constraint on pointer receiver inGolang

Tags: go, generics

I may have missed something in the golang generics specifications and I have a weird situation that I cannot seem to find answer for.

The gist is that I want to define a method that receives parameters whose pointer receiver implements a particular interface. I need it to be pointer receiver as to mutate the struct implementing the interface.

Here is a simplified example of the problematic situation.  https://go.dev/play/p/Lw256Mh1pGH

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Doer interface {
    Do()
}

type Thing struct {
    used int
}

var _ Doer = &Thing{}

func (t *Thing) Do() {
    t.used++
    fmt.Println("Doing my thing.")
}

func Append[T Doer](list []T, constructor func() *T) []T {
    v := constructor()
    v.Do()
    return append(list, *v)
}

func main() {
    constructor := func() *Thing { return &Thing{} }
    s := make([]Thing, 0)
    s = Append(s, constructor)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

So you see there are two errors. Even if I accept the constructor to return a Thing and not a pointer possibly resulting in many allocations I still cannot make a call to `Do()`. Below is the more verbose error.

```
Thing does not implement Doer: wrong method signature
    got  func (*Thing).Do()
    want func (Doer).Do()
```

I wonder how to specify the type constraint such that it validates the pointer receiver. I guess I am missing some syntax?

For the time being I can workaround by providing a wrapper function to call the `Do()` function. https://play.golang.com/p/AS6YN_IsgHi

```golang
func Append[T any](list []T, constructor func() *T, do func(*T)) []T {
    v := constructor()
    do(v)
    return append(list, *v)
}

func main() {
    constructor := func() *Thing { return &Thing{} }
    s := make([]Thing, 0)

    s = Append(s, constructor, func(t *Thing) { t.Do() })

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Apologies for the possibly silly question. I just cannot figure out how to tell golang to check types constraints on the pointer receiver. I tried things like `[T *Doer]`, `[&T Doer]` and could not get them to work.

Comment: To explain the more complex use case I am trying to complete. I want to use generics in array deserialization. So for every element in the array I want to call a constructor function to allocate the memory (*T) and subsequently call a deserialization function with parameter pointer to the newly created object implementing specific interface  to unmarshall the fields of the constructed object. The constructed object has to be appended to an array

Comment: ^ Which brings to this: https://go.dev/play/p/myw6FAosPjK

Comment: @blackgreen thank you. This seems to be the answer. I will try it in bit.

Comment: @blackgreen I hit a stack overflow inside the go compiler when doing type checks. :-)

It may be my data model. I try to serialize self referential structures (tree, linked list) in my tests. 

I think your solution is correct yet there is apparently issue in the go compiler. So I cannot apply it. I will try to isolate and possibly file a bug to golang.

Comment: Go issue for reference: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51832

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're getting caught up between pointers that implement an interface, and pointers to the interface.  The general rule is, keep pointers on the concrete type side, use interfaces for the general side.

`*Thing` implments Doer, but as far as `Append` is concerned, its just dealing with `Doer`.

```
func Append[T Doer](list []T, constructor func() *T) []T
```

the list is of type `T`.  The return is a list of type `T`.  Why is does the constructor return *T?

`*Thing` might be the concrete type behind your `Doer`, but that's up to the implementation.  `Append` just deals with `Doer`.

```
    return append(list, *v)
```

Same here.  Why are you dereferencing `v`?  Constructor should return a `Doer`.  List is of `Doer`s.  So add `append(list, v)` with no dereferencing required.

Finally, `[]Thing` is not the right type for your list.

```
    constructor := func() *Thing { return &Thing{} }
    s := make([]Thing, 0)
```

Your constructor returns *Thing but your list is of Thing.  Since `*Thing` implements `Doer`, we should `make([]*Thing, 0)` instead.

```
func Append[T Doer](list []T, constructor func() T) []T {
    v := constructor()
    v.Do()
    return append(list, v)
}

func main() {
    constructor := func() *Thing { return &Thing{} }
    s := make([]*Thing, 0)
    s = Append(s, constructor)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Complete example https://go.dev/play/p/K2oAy6gl2q8

Comment: thank you. Indeed working with pointer types only solves the compilation issue.  However that changes a bit the semantics. `[]T` and `[]*T` differ in 2 significant ways. First there is the semantics of having or not `nil` values. Second is the memory size and performance when processing the data. For small structures like statistics the overhead of N pointers may be significant e.g. factor of 2 or 1.5.